# How to Execute SSIS package using c# code by passing Excel Connection Manager as a variable?

Tags: c#, ssis, package

I'm Having a SSIS Package with 2 connection Managers one to Connect with Database and one is Excel Connection Manager I want to run the SSIS Package using c# code by Passing Excel Connection Manager and the Database Connections  Dynamically.What are all steps i need to do for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the dtexec.exe program and pass the connection managers in the same call. For examples,  please refer to BOL [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx).